# Shows "beamer.cls" not found, "pstcol.sty" not found and few more

Tags: errors, installing

I was doing my semester project work. I had completed it few weeks ago. Now I am supposed to make a presentation for it. For making the report I was using my old laptop. I had completed 50% of my presentation on the old laptop.  Everything was going well but the laptop stopped working. Now I am working on another laptop  but during compliation it shows multiple errors. Another option was to use overleaf but I am unable to work on Overleaf because of network issues.

After getting the new laptop, I installed Basic MiKTeX (install packages on the fly) and TeXstudio. But everytime I compile it shows that `beamer.cls` is not found. Then I opened MiKtTeX console and installed `beamer`, then I compiled my program again, and it shows `**** not found`. **** is something I don't remember.

Further I compiled my report (which was completed using the old laptop) and it says `pstcol.sty not found`. I have been trying this for the last 36 hours but I am unable to figure out anything.

What should I do?

Comment: If packages are missing you will have to install them until everything is there. The easiest is to install every package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then how do I install every package? And how big it is?

Comment: "install packages on the fly" or in the next  fly, or even later ... your mileage may vary. specially if there packages dependencies and network issues.

Comment: You can go to the miktex console, to the package tab and select whatever you want to install. On my machine the full miktex takes up around 7 GB. But if you have network issues and on-the-fly doesn't work properly (which can happen) you will probably have to install the missing packages one after the other as you did install beamer.